# Как использовать позиционирование в процентах для позиционирования в Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap, sass

Имеется некоторая вложенность из контейнеров в которых сетки для размещения контента, в которых тоже сетки для размещения контента. И в определенный момент мне потребовалось разместить элементы в процентном соотношении к экрану. Но у `bootstrap` нет понятия размеры и следовательно значения в процентах не работают. `vw` и `vh` не работают на `ios`, как быть? неужели только с `js`?

Comment: "Но у bootstrap нет понятия размеры" - это как? Стилями любые размеры делаются. Надо в % относительно всего экрана или родительского контейнера?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, да, нужно относительно всего экрана. можно как-то сделать с помощью css?

Comment: Т.е., если я правильно понял. Целевой объект находится во вложенных контейнерах, которые имеют позиционирование в соответствии с сеткой бутстрапа, но сам целевой объект должен быть позиционирован относительно экрана. т.е. относительно <body> ?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov, да, это не возможно? Ведь я даже не знаю какое позиционирование у элементов со стилями bs..

Comment: У бутстрапа сетка в % из 12 колонок. Когда вы указываете col-sm-6, то это (грубо говоря) займет 100%/12*6 от размеров родительского контейнера. Спозиционировать вложенный элемент относительно корня страницы получится только если он сам и его родители имеют css-атрибут position: absolute. Но этого в бутстрапе точно нет. 
Честно говоря мне как-то смутно представляется конечная цель такой разметки

Comment: @DmitryKozlov вот когда Вы пишите комментарий, то поле ввода и кнопки "комментрировать" и "скрыть справку" находятся на одной оси. А на мобильнике это не удобно, нужно чтобы кнопки находились по полем ввода. Но прижатые к самому вверху не будет красиво, нужно же их вертикально по все странице разместить. Согласны? Или это как-то по другому делается?

Comment: Разумеется по другому. В бутстрапе это делается комбинированием стилей. Чтобы скрыть/показать или по разному расположить в зависимости от размера экрана http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: @DmitryKozlov то есть делается две разные разметки и они друг друга заменяют, срываясь и наоборот появляясь? Я блин пару часов назад об этом спрашивал и мне сказали что нужно стили переопределять.. Да ЭТО ЖЕ ВЫ И БЫЛИ!) Так как нужно делать?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid, http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities ну и гуглинг с ключевыми словами responsive bootstrap. Вы хотя бы на домашней странице бутстрапа пробовали уменьшить окно браузера или посмотреть в режиме эмуляции телефона?

Comment: @DmitryKozlov я Вас не понимаю! Вы мне показываете классы, которые СКРЫВАЮТ HTML ТЕГИ. И именно об этом я и спрашивал в прошлый раз, цитата - или же создать ещё один html шаблон и подставлять его при подходящем медиа-запросе, а основной прятать? И Вы скзали что нужно отдельно стили писать. И ещё Вы мне даете ссылку на grid, зачем? Я знаю как писать сетки, но я не могу понять как они мне могут помочь, при чем вообще сетки для кнопок?? Объясните как нужно, только по человечески, а то Вы бота напоминаете который по ключивым словам ответы ищет и не может понять что вообще не в тему.

Comment: Можно указать разные стили колонок для разных размеров экрана. если укажите <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12"></div><div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12"></div> то на большом экране они будут рядом, а на маленьком друг под другом

Answer (score 1):

Как вы не можете задать размеры в `%`, если у `bootstrap` процентное позиционирование.

Вот немного стандартных `media`-запросов, внутри которых можете задавать все что вам нужно:

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```